# Writing from JTextArea to File, No Break Lines?

Tags: java, swing, file-io, newline, jtextarea

Ok I can type into the JTextArea and save it to a file, however when I open the file in notepad for example it has no breaklines. When loaded back into my program the file has the breaklines again.

I want to know why this happens, whats the point why not just have it the same?
and how to make the format be the same when outputting to file so it is the same as it looks in the JTextArea.

In the JTextArea api I do not see any methods that give me any clue on how to do this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of `Notepad` is most probably not recognizing "unix" end of line sequences (also used/produced by some Java libraries).  Try with another text editor.  If I remember correctly, `Wordpad` makes a better job.  If not this, you should post code and operating environment.

Comment: Yes it seems only notepad does this. But since it is the default editor on most windows os it is kind of annoying. Thanks though!

Comment: @Steve  One alternative is to manipulate the text on write and then read so it's compatible with `Notepad`.  However, almost everything else has moved away from this convention.  I don't think it's worth the effort.  If you save the file with extension `.wri`, it should open with `Wordpad` by default.

Answer (score 1):

> I can type into the JTextArea and save it to a file,

How are you saving the file?

> In the JTextArea api I do not see any methods that give me any clue on how to do this

Use the `textArea.write(...)` method to save the file. It will save the file with the proper end of line string for the current platform you are using.

See [Text and New Lines](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/text-and-new-lines/) for more information.